# One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build

erro : One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to D:\Flutter Project\ivy\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
compileSdkVersion 33
...
}

This is my app/build.gradle code

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 33
compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.ivy"
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
    // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
    minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Isn't it already fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
compileSdkVersion 33
compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
```

why are you using `compileSdkVersion` twice..?
change it to this instead...

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 33
ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

You were over-riding the `compileSdkVersion` with `flutter.compileSdkVersion`

Answer (score 0):

```
    android {
compileSdkVersion 33
compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion //REMOVE THIS LINE
ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.ivy"
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
    // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
    minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Comment: Can you add more context? And not just purely code?

Comment: Highlighted main context to change, and the questioner understands this. @Lawrence Gimenez

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).